# What features should I look for in a vessel for making Indian curd (yogurt / Dahi)?

Tags: milk, yogurt

What is the most suitable vessel to make perfect curd without any liquid in it? If that true that a clay vessel will be good for it because clay will absorb liquid and the remaining thing you get will be curd?

[image: Curd / Dahi / Yogurt]

PS:  this image is just for reference. As there were some misunderstanding regarding for what curd i was asking.

And the clay vessel i am talking about look like this(In india we call it "Kulhad") :

[image: Clay Pot]

Comment: By "curd" are you referring to a soft, drained, cheese like paneer or cottage cheese? Curds for harder cheeses are handled differently. Alternatively- lemon curd is a custard but doesn't match your description.

Comment: I've edited assuming you mean yogurt. (Curd is basically just a variety of yogurt, and yogurt is the more widely understood term.) If I'm mistaken, please feel free to roll back and explain what you really meant!

Comment: @Sobachatina see the milk tag, not lemon curd. But yes different curds are handled differently. My marscapone never goes into a vessel, once the cream has been cooked and curdled with lemon juice, it hangs in a handkerchief and gets used the next day.

Comment: "what is curd?": http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/35823/1672

Comment: Hey sorry for late.. But yes its not cheese or lemon curd, It's what we indian say Dahi which is Yogurt as @Jefromi mentioned

Answer (score 1):

The slight ability of clay to soak up whey doesn't matter, you won't really notice much difference with it. Just use any vessel that is convenient - glass, metal, plastic, glazed or unglazed clay, other ceramics will all work.

If you want curd without whey, you have to use a method which produces less whey (usually, that needs slower fermentation at lower temperatures) and/or strain the curd. Do it in a cheesecloth overnight under its own weight, don't press it like paneer. The vessel is not important.

In principle, better isolation can give you more stable temperatures and thus ensure better fermantation, possibly giving you curd with less whey. In this sense, the thicker the walls and the less heat-conductive your vessel, the better for curd. This would be a reason to use clay, ceramics or glass. But it can be easily offset by using more isolation for your fermenting environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use a clay dish to absorb the liquid, it has to be unglazed clay. The dish in your picture won't absorb anything. I would also wonder about how you get a clay (terracotta) dish clean if it has liquid (presumably whey) soaked in. It may be a traditional approach that works well for daily use but not occasional use.

Comment: The image is just to show what curd it.. As there were misunderstanding about the curd. Its just to show what curd i am talking about

Comment: We can put that dish under direct sun light to make it dry.. And the Dish i am talking about is called "Kulhad" in India

Comment: That looks like the sort of thing I was thinking of - unglazed in a google image search.  But the right-hand kulhad in the second picture has liquid in it (and looks glazed inside).  Direct sunlight is perhaps more of an option for you than me (in the UK), I'd have to dry it in the oven.  Even so that would only remove the water, not the protein etc in the whey.

Comment: You can use it again though.. And in UK you have to use oven.. lol